# Сохранение нужного value значения в БД с проверкой

Tags: wordpress

Приветствую всех!
В кодексе вордпресса описывается процесс добавление произвольных полей для пользователя, но нет чекбоксов.
Сделал вот такую рабочую функцию:

```
function userff($user) {
    $special = get_the_author_meta('special',$user->ID );
?>
<ul>
<li><input value="выбор1" name="special"<?php if ($special == 'выбор1') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> type="radio" /> Выбор 1</li>
<li><input value="выбор2" name="special"<?php if ($special == 'выбор2') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> type="radio" /> Выбор 2</li>
</ul>
<?php }
add_action( 'edit_user_profile',    'userff' );

function save_user_profile_more( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {return false;}
        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'special', sanitize_text_field($_POST['special']) );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update',  'save_user_profile_more' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_profile_more' );
```

При выборе любого чекбокса, в таблциу usermeta заносятся значения: выбор1 или выбор2. Как сделать проверку, чтобы в значении value сохранялись те данные, что есть и нельзя было через редактор кода прописать свое. То есть зашел пользователь, открыл в браузере просмотр кода, сменил значение value и нажал сохранить, в итоге его значение и сохранилось в таблицу.

Comment: не использовать значение value как основу для записи, а передавать в обработчик только сам факт какой чек-бокс нажат.

Comment: Если не вникать в правильность данного кода, то очевидно, что нужно делать такую проверку для передаваемого массива $_POST['special'].